# NSDate variable as nil

Tags: swift, sqlite, nsdate

An init method for Person class looks like

```
init (id:int64, firstName:String, lastName:String, birthDay:NSDate?)
```

As you can see birthDay is an optional, because we don't always have the birthday.

The data comes from a SQLite database. A date type does not exist in SQLite so the date is represented as a string (which can be NULL). To convert that string to an NSDate I created an extension to NSDate :

```
extension NSDate: Value {
    public class var declaredDatatype: String {
        return String.declaredDatatype
    }
    public class func fromDatatypeValue(stringValue: String) -> NSDate {
        return SQLDateFormatter.dateFromString(stringValue)!
    }
    public var datatypeValue: String {
        return SQLDateFormatter.stringFromDate(self)
    }
}
```

So when creating a person:

```
let person = Person(id: row[id], firstName: row[first_name], lastName: row[last_name], birthDay:NSDate.fromDatatypeValue(row[birthday]!))
```

will fail if the birthday string is NULL. (I have to unwrap the row[birthday]! as expects a non-optional String, and this may/can not be changed)

So my idea was to test for this before creating the person

```
 var birthday : NSDate
            if let birthdayString = row[Person.birthday] {
                birthday = NSDate.fromDatatypeValue(birthdayString)
            } else {
                birthday=nil
            }
```

and the use birthday in the init function.

BUT swift tells me : Cannot assign a value of type 'nil' to a value of 'NSDate'

How can this be solved ?

PS. : I know I could have an if and 2 initializers but I'd rather not have as my Person init func has 12 parameters (for reasons of simplicity I've only used 4 above) and maintaining this is a pita

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do the following.

```
var birthday : NSDate? = nil
if let birthdayString = row[Person.birthday] {
    birthday = NSDate.fromDatatypeValue(birthdayString)
}
```